Does the pressure recovery become not as extreme as you speed up?
Does the pressure recovery area on a wing become not as intense as you speed up? If so, why?
The pressure recovery is the effect that decelerates the air after it has been accelerated by the airfoil. When you speed up, is this force reduced?


Here is a photo I found. (Ignore the arrows and the lines) So as you can see, the red area (low pressure) dissipates towards the rear of the airfoil. This is the pressure recovery area.
Does that pressure recovery effect decrease as you increase speed? If so, why does the pressure recovery area not recover as much pressure as you speed up?
(The low pressure also dissipates towards the tip of the wing, but that's not important to this question)
When air goes over the top of the airfoil, it will get accelerated, and therefore turn low pressure. In this picture, the red area is where this is happening. When the air is done accelerating and it is reaching the rear portion of the wing, it will start to decelerate due to the atmospheric pressure. The area of deceleration is the pressure recovery area.
This question is asking if this pressure recovery effect will decrease as you increase speed. (and if it does, why that is the case)
Here's my theory of why the pressure recovery becomes not as intense as you increase speed:

(In this case imagine the plate is an airfoil. It's hard to draw an airfoil, so I just used a plate as an example)
Imagine you have an airfoil facing into the wind. Like this one:
The blue arrows represent the airflow. So in this case, (if the flow is compressible) there would be high pressure on the front of it, and low pressure on the back. Not very surprising.
Now, put it at an angle.
In this case, there is still high pressure on the (now bottom) part of it, and there is still low pressure on the top. These effects are reduced, though. (because of the angle)
Remember that the adverse pressure gradient is the force that decelerates the flow after it has been accelerated by the wing. (it can also cause stalls to occur).
So in the picture above, the angle of the plate causes it to have low pressure above it (along with the effect of the airfoil shape causing low pressure, but I'm ignoring that). Because of this effect that makes the air above the plate low pressure, wouldn't the adverse pressure gradient or pressure recovery also become lower pressure? Meaning that the adverse pressure wouldn't be as strong?

"the back pressure decreases as you increase speed" do you mean Bernoulli?

maybe what he's asking about is just as the aircraft begins to move...  This aspect is discussed in detail by Jones.

Sorry everyone, this seems like it's a hard to understand question. Maybe @sophit this answer / question will help explain what I'm asking. Basically, where the pressure recovery is, that force, why does it change as you speed up. Bernoulli will change the pressure on the wing, but what changes the back pressure on the wing. The back pressure is the force decelerating the air at the rear of the airfoil. Will edit the question to make it more clear.

Hey, Wyatt - some of us are low speed people (literally), and need a moment to get our heads around this.  We don't think so much about compressibility issues and Mach effects, but consider flight issues below Mach 0.3+/- where this is not a problem.

@sophit Did that edit help somewhat? If not I can try to improve it some more.

@ThomasPerry Oh okay haha. I understand that. Maybe that edit I just did helped out?

"When the air is done accelerating and it is reaching the rear portion of the wing, it will start to decelerate due to the atmospheric pressure" not really.due to the atmospheric pressure, it starts decelerating AND the pressure raising just because this is the effect of airfoil upon the air flowing around it.

The example with the vertical airfoil is not helpful because it is dominated by separated flow whereas the effect you mention first is happening in the linear range of aerodynamics where flow is attached. Also, high pressure in the front is the consequence of stagnating flow, not compressibility.

I find it very hard to understand your questions because you choose strange wording for things which have proper names already.
Why should there be a change in the pressure distribution as speed increases? We can use dimensionless parameters (coefficients) to describe a pressure distribution because speed has no influence on it. It does have an influence on the absolute pressure change (that grows with the square of speed), but not the distribution. This is especially true at low Mach numbers; once you cross into transsonic flow, the Mach number increase from the speed increase will have an effect on the pressure distribution.
What you probably mean is the change due to a lower angle of attack as the airplane flies faster but still needs the same lift to fly. With the increase in speed the angle of attack has to be reduced to keep the forces in equilibrium.
From potential flow theory we know that the pressure distribution over an airfoil is the linear combination of lift due to angle of attack plus lift due to camber. A lower angle of attack reduces its share of the total so that the resulting pressure distribution more and more resembles the pure camber distribution as angle of attack is reduced.
Since pressure variations grow with the square of speed, I cannot agree that any pressure should "reduce as speed goes up". Suction will get stronger, as will dynamic pressure, but neither will be reduced.
So far, I have left density out of the picture. Include it, and it will be better to use dynamic pressure as a proxy for speed. You can always trade an increase in speed for a decrease in density; that is why airliners want to fly high up in the troposphere.
Dynamic pressure can be seen as equivalent to the stiffness of a spring. Increase it, and forces will increase and oscillations will speed up. That is why higher dynamic pressure will also cause higher absolute pressure variations. There is only one standard speed at which pressure changes, and that is the speed of sound. In fully subsonic flow, pressures will adjust practically immediately to changes in the flow field.

"It does have an influence on the absolute pressure change (that grows with the square of speed), but not the distribution." Interesting. So say you're traveling at mach 0.2. The air accelerates over the top of the wing and turns low pressure. If you go faster (say mach 0.4), the air will be even lower pressure. The air (mach 0.4) will have less time to 're pressurize' when it is going faster over the foil (re pressurize after it's been accelerated), so wouldn't that mean the air traveling off of the rear of the airfoil would still be low pressure? Both mach 0.2 and 0.4 cases at the same AoA.

Something I needed to include : The reason it will take longer for the air to ' re pressurize' is because it is lower pressure. It takes more time to fill a section of air that is a vacuum than it does to fill a section of air that's just a few psi below atmospheric, for example.

(If that doesn’t make sense I will make an edit to my question)

@Wyatt See, now I understand much better where you are stuck. Please see the added paragraph, it should not really surprise you after all what you have read here already. And yes, please edit your question, so others will be less confused than I was yesterday.

@Wyatt and please change the awful "back pressure" phrase to something better suited. You used "pressure recovery" yourself, so please stick to the accepted phrases.

I see, that edit helped a lot! I will be editing this question, and also changing the back pressure phrase. Thanks.

I edited the question, let me know if there's anything else I could improve!

@Wyatt Oh boy, where do I start ... pressure recovery is an effect, not a force. And why should it shrink when speed increases? Please name your source or ask an open question. When you start with an incorrect assumption you will not arrive at a better understanding when you do not question that assumption. ALL forces grow more intense when you speed up, so please stop thinking that some force will decrease when speed increases (and all other parameters stay constant).

Ah okay. I make another edit changing "force" to "effect". I also attempted to explain why I thought the pressure recovery effect would shrink as speed increased. I'm not too confident that it will make sense, but I will keep trying.

@Wyatt Please do not simply change single words and append new stuff at the end. Instead, rework the whole text so it becomes consistent. And don't say "it is well known", followed by a falsehood. Better ask an open question ("Is it true that ... if yes, why?")

I removed the part about the pressure distribution of the wing changing, because that isn't really what this question is about. (although I did ask you follow up questions about that) I also removed the statements, and turned them into questions. Is that better? It seems to still be getting downvoted, so maybe not. After following your advice I think the question looks a lot better, so not sure why.

@Wyatt What you call a photo is actually a drawing I made with Inkscape for this answer.

Yes that’s exactly where I got the drawing. (Looks very professional!) I can edit the question again to add the source.

@Wyatt No, no, i don't need attribution, but please do not call it a photo!

Oh okay, I also think drawing is more appropriate.

It may be, in a relative sense, that delta P is less because the Volume of air passing over the wing (to produce the same amount of lift) will be greater.
For the same lift at higher speed, angle of attack will be less, and the amount of deflection of the airstream is less.
Keep in mind the downwash created by the bottom of the wing also lowers pressure behind the wing and may contribute to the acceleration of air over the top of the wing.
If the wing moves more rapidly away from a given parcel of air, one might also imagine, relative to the wing, pressure is lower.
An analogy might be the Doppler effect with sound.  The whistle of a passing train drops in pitch as it passes, just as a person on the train would notice the same effect if a stationary person sounded a horn.
